# Is the tensor product $L^\infty(X)\times L^\infty(Y)$ dense in $L^\infty(X\times Y)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, lp-spaces

Is tensor product $L^\infty(X)\times L^\infty(Y)$ dense in $L^\infty(X\times Y)$ where $X, Y\subset \mathbb R^n$? and does any body know an example of a function $\psi \in L^\infty(X)\times L^\infty(Y)$ such that it can not be written as a series $\psi=\sum_ix_i(t)y_i(s)$
where $x_i(t)\in L^\infty(X)$ and $y_i\in L^\infty(Y)$.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $L_\infty(Y)$ a typo for $L^\infty(Y)$?

Comment: ohh yes inded it is

Comment: x @user131195: Well, fix it then. There's an "edit" link under your question.